# Removing old emails from newest thread php

Tags: php, email, imap

I have the following structure:

```
$email = array(
      4 => array(
          4,  //contains email messages from uids 4 + 3 + 2
          3,  //contains email messages from uids 3 + 2
          2   //contains email message from uid 2
));
```

What I'd like to accomplish is:

```
$email = array(
      4 => array(
          4,  //contains email messages from uid 4
          3,  //contains email messages from uid 3
          2   //contains email message from uid 2
));
```

My thoughts are that I need to grab the message from the end of the stack, and recursively traverse the tree upwards and do a `str_replace` against the contents, leaving only the contents from that specific email. I can't figure out how to do this.

Also,

I've noticed that there are instances where for example when viewing message uid 4, it will say something like:

`On Jul 19, 2013, at 3:28 PM, jonathan@somedomain.com wrote:`

And also sometimes it will display the new message, than the old message, than after that the signature from the new message:

Jonathan,

{{new message here}}

> Steve,
>
> {{old message}}
>
> Jonathan

Thanks,
Steve

dash dash dash

**I have no real idea how to implement this. I hope I worded my question correctly and provided enough information to assist.**

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
<?php

$threads = array(
    'baz bar foo' => array(
        'baz bar foo',
        'bar foo',
        'foo',
    ),
);

$new_threads = array();

foreach ($threads as $key => $thread) {

    $tmp = array();
    $prev = null;

    foreach (array_reverse($thread) as $email) {
        switch (true) {
            case $prev === null;
            case ($pos = strrpos($email, $prev)) === false:
                $tmp[] = $email;
                $prev = $email;
                break;
            default:
                $tmp[] = rtrim(substr($email, 0, $pos));
                $prev = $email;
        }
    }

    $new_threads[$key] = array_reverse($tmp);

}

var_dump($new_threads);
```

Comment: That looks great, and Im going to test it, but what do I do about the adding content email applications put in, like "On this day Jonathan wrote this:" Theres so many variations, i feel like its impossible to achieve what I want.

Comment: You can use PCRE functions for your purpose.http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Comment: Thats the issue. I had a feeling regular expression was going to be needed. I have no experience using regular expressions. I could try it out myself, but its going to take an extremely long time and most likely not going to be right. I have every anticipation of learning regular expressions, but I cant do it at this time. Can you assist? Is there a way to replace everything but the message, or do I need to find all the different variations and do regular expressions against all of them. I'm lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

it works!
http://ideone.com/qXysl3

```
<?php

$msg1 = <<< EOD
Steve,

old message

Jonathan
EOD;

$msg2 = <<< EOD
Jonathan,

new message

On Jul 19, 2013, at 3:28 PM, jonathan@somedomain.com wrote:
{$msg1}

Thanks, Steve
EOD;


$threads = array(
    $msg2 => array(
        $msg2,
        $msg1,
    ),
);


$quote = 'On [a-z]{3} \\d{1,2}, \\d{4}, at \\d{1,2}:\\d{2} (?:AM|PM), [^@\\s]++@[^\\s]++ wrote:';

$new_threads = array();

foreach ($threads as $key => $thread) {

    $tmp = array();
    $prev = null;

    foreach (array_reverse($thread) as $email) {
        if ($prev === null) {
            $tmp[] = $prev = $email;
        } else {
            $pattern = sprintf('/(?:%s|%s)[\\s]*+/i', $quote, preg_quote($prev));
            $tmp[] = $prev = preg_replace($pattern, '', $email);
        } 
    }

    $new_threads[$key] = array_reverse($tmp);

}

foreach ($new_threads as $key => $value) {
    echo "[all]\n{$key}\n\n";
    echo "[msg2]\n{$value[0]}\n\n";
    echo "[msg1]\n{$value[1]}\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you account for when they put the message in right arrows. Sorry, im on my phone so theres no right arrow symbol.

Comment: Im going to find out other types of content that gets added by apps to the emails so we can get this fully complete. I appreciate the work very much.

Comment: It is nearly impossible to remove reply context from messages. There are say formats and styles and no standard that the best you can do is some heuristics.

Comment: I know. I'm trying as hard as I can to do as much heuristics as possible. It's extremely difficult because I don't know or have the time allocated at the moment to learn regex, and I hate asking people for help on it.

Comment: @CertaiN, Can you add a regex expression for the following:  newline then "Quoting jonathan@someemail.com:" then newline then prior email in right arrow brackets.

Comment: @CertaiN, it would be best to try and do the regex against quoting and then until the last bracket or pipe.

Comment: @CertaiN, one last thing. Theres usually a link just above that says Show Quoted Text or Hide Quoted text. How do I deal with that? Is that just added by the email application?